# Realm object as member is nil after saving

Tags: ios, database, swift, realm

I'm facing an issue where a Realm object has another Realm object as member which is always `nil` after adding to the database.

```
class MedPack: Object {

    dynamic var uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
    dynamic var medicine: Medicine?

    convenience init(medicine: Medicine) {
        self.init()
        self.medicine = medicine
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "uuid"
    }
}
```

The reference to the object `Medicine` is always nil after adding.

```
class Medicine: Object {

    var uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
    var name: String?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "uuid"
    }
}
```

Creation of object

```
let medPack = MedPack(medicine: med)
```

Adding to database

```
static let sharedInstance = DBHelper()
var realmDb: Realm!

private init() {
    realmDb = try! Realm()
}

func store(object: Object) {
    try! self.realmDb.write {
        self.realmDb.add(object)
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you detecting that object is nil? watch window always show nil for instance members no matter if this is true or not. I'd say that's related to the lazy nature of realm objects

Comment: @ClaudioRedi When I fetch the objects from the database, the `Medicine` object does not get saved, but `MedPack` is saved.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, what is the MBObject that Medicine subclasses?

Comment: @caseynolan Sorry, this should also be just `Object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After comparing this code to one of the Realm sample projects, it would appear that simply setting an `Object` as a child of another does not implicitly write it to the database as well.

Instead, you may need to refactor your code slightly, but make sure you explicitly add your `Medicine` object to Realm in a write transaction, before you set its relation to `MedPack` and then write `MedPack` to the database.